# Views Term ID (with depth) greater than specific depth value

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'ved used [Taxonomy Views Integrator](http://drupal.org/project/views_exclude_previous) to take over my taxonomy terms pages.

I'd like to have the main view **only** show items beneath the term in the hierarchy and a views attachment (above) that shows the items **directly** at that level of the hierarchy.

So far this works perfectly except that "Term ID (with depth)" only care how far to look rather than where to start. **I'd like the depth to be greater than 1.**

- Is this possible with another approach perhaps?
- I don't understand what "Term ID depth modifier" does at all, maybe that's the key?
- Maybe I need a relationship to accomplish this?

Views offers the concept of exclusion when taking arguments, but that only works for node IDs. Is there a way to extend this?

---

Looks like I might be stuck using [Views Exclude Previous](http://drupal.org/project/views_exclude_previous) because the exclude option is missing from Drupal-6 Views-2.x.

SEE: http://drupal.org/node/733686

From that thread it seems to work in Drupal-7 Views-3.x, but not for me :(